# Twilio Read message

Tags: node.js, twilio

I've been trying to code a bot using Twilio's API that needs to read the message the user sent, I've been looking at the docs for around 3-5 hours and tried almost everything, I am aware that there is a question like this but the solution didn't work

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const MessagingResponse =require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.post('/sms',(req,res)=>{
var msg = req


var messageR = req.body
var msg= res.body
var something=res.body
console.log(messageR,msg,something,res)
//testing what does and doesnt work 

//send messge

const twiml =new MessagingResponse();
twiml.message('Message recived')
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/xml'})
res.end(twiml.toString());

});
http.createServer(app).listen(1337,()=>{

    console.log("Express server listening on port 1337")
})
```

Im working with node.js

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry if this is a waste of your time!

Comment: Later versions of express don’t need to require body parser. Use: // Body Parser Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: Can you expand? i dont really understand? Thank you so much tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As of Express version 4.16.0 (which came out 3 years ago!), [Express basically comes with body parser out of the box](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)--to use this Express-version of body parser, you can pretty much just search bodyParser, and substitute it with Express!

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/hack', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  // Access the message body and the number it was sent from.
  const inbMsg = req.body.Body;
  if(inbMsg == "matcha") {
    twiml.message('The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!');
  }
  else {
      twiml.message("else");
  }
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
});
```